# using Array value instead of checkbox_id in if statement

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, checkbox

I have a checkbox with id: `Pencilbox`.   Now I have an array in which the first column contains the name of objects, names are equal to their checkbox id, and the second column is the price of them. so
Array:

```
  Pencil    5
  Pen       6
  Notebook  10
```

Now I want to find the price of objects that the user wants. So normally I have to use:

```
if (Pencilbix.ischecked) {...}
```

But now, I want to use the first column of the array (as the string is equal to the checkbox id) instead of checkbox id, or:

```
if (Array[0][0].toString.ischecked) {...}
```

But it is wrong. 
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use `findViewById()` method to get view by id and check its state:

```
val array = arrayOf(arrayOf(R.id.Pencilbox, 5), arrayOf(R.id.Penbox, 6), arrayOf(R.id.Notebookbox, 10))

// in Activity
if (findViewById<CheckBox>(array[0][0]).isChecked) {...}

// in Fragment
if (view?.findViewById<CheckBox>(array[0][0])?.isChecked == true) {...}
```

Comment: What if I have to read the array from a csv file? In practice, my array is a big dataset with 9 columns.

Comment: Also, when I use your method, I got the error:  array[0][0] should be in Int

Comment: If you use android please add appropriate tags to your question.

Comment: You get the error bcz `findViewById()` method accepts only `Int` parameters.

Comment: Great thanks. The guy who corrected my question, deleted the information corresponding to android. I had told that I am using android, kotlin,